# How to extend TextInputFormatter to limit a Range of numbers AND format to 1 decimal place ("000.0") . In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The idea is to limit the user to input any value from 0 to any given Max Value.

This is the code I have thus far. It does work to limit the max value, but it's not allowing me to work with decimals (Exemple: 10.7, 35.3, 98.2, etc...)

```
class CustomRangeTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final double maxValue;

  CustomRangeTextInputFormatter({@required this.maxValue});

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    if (newValue.text == '')
      return TextEditingValue();
    else if (int.parse(newValue.text) < 0) return TextEditingValue().copyWith(text: '0');

    return int.parse(newValue.text) > maxValue ? TextEditingValue().copyWith(text: maxValue.toString()) : newValue;
  }
}
```

How can I improve this code to allow the user to use decimals, while limiting it to 1 decimal place?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below using String method 'indexOf' and 'substring'.

```
class CustomRangeTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final double maxValue;
  final int decimalLengthLimit;

  CustomRangeTextInputFormatter(
      {@required this.maxValue, @required this.decimalLengthLimit});

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    if (newValue.text.contains('.')) {
      return TextEditingValue().copyWith(text: oldValue.text);
    }
    if (newValue.text.isEmpty) {
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: '',
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
      );
    }

    if (newValue.text.length == 1) {
      return TextEditingValue().copyWith(text: newValue.text);
    } else {
      return TextEditingValue().copyWith(text: newValue.text.substring(1, 2));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Kuku. It didn't work out for me here. It's only registering the one digit. I'm attaching a GIF to show: shorturl.at/jCY45

Comment: I can not see 'shorturl.at/jCY45' GIF.

Comment: You mean that you want to limit decimal length by variable?

Comment: @LeonidasYopan I added CustomRangeTextInputFormatter's parameter to control decimal limit length.

Comment: And you need to change 'int.parse' to 'double.parse'.

Comment: Sorry about the GIF. Here it is: https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/5adda0f8-5046-42cc-95c6-167623043e08/problem-with-range-and-decimals.gif?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45O3KS52Y5%2F20201009%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201009T181249Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=b1b65f1c561cb20288110127faad5aa941d1d3f622e7931367c5014194b65c23&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%20%3D%22problem-with-range-and-decimals.gif%22